# CSS Inner shadow not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css

My CSS for creating an inner shadow is not working in IE.

For example:

```
<tr>
    <td align="left" ><a href="#"><img src="images/beverlySmith.gif" class="imagedropshadow" /></a> </td>
</tr>
```

My CSS is:

```
.imagedropshadow {
padding: 5px;
border: solid 1px #EFEFEF;
}
a:hover img.imagedropshadow {
-moz-box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 10px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 20px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 20px #ffffff;
}
```

It works in Mozilla. But not in IE8. How can I fix this with IE?

Comment: Which IE?  There are several, you know :-)

Comment: this has nothing to do with javascript or php btw, it is purely css, and more specifically its css3.

Comment: I'm sure it has something to do with *moz*-box-shadow

Comment: @Matt , -moz is just a prefix for firefox, IE and webkit browsers just ignore it, but IE 9 and only 9 will render just plain box-shadow.

Comment: @mcbeav i'm quite aware. the original post (before it was edited) did not have the other prefixes ;)

Comment: ah, sorry about that, when i saw it, it was there but looked as if it was commented out. sorry again.

Answer (score 3):

It will not work in IE 8 or earlier. the prefix -moz is specifically for firefox, -webkit is specifically for webkit based browsers, such as safari and chrome, and box-shadow is the standard.

Answer (score 3):

You can [see here](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/) the browser support of that CSS3 feature.

Here it is for the lazy amongst us. :)[image]